# Not showing the widget wrapped with Obx in Android 14

Tags: flutter, mobile, release, flutter-getx, android-14

**When I use Obx in debug mode the taskt widget is displayed but in release mode in Android 14 the widget is not displayed, but removing Obx solves this problem, even replacing it with Get builder still solves the problem can be**

```
class SMSPage extends GetView<GetLicenseController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SMS'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: Get.width,
        height: Get.height,
        child: Center(
          child: Obx(() => Text(
                'sender:${controller.sender} \n message:${controller.body} \n time recive:${controller.timeRecived}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```